# Extending 'if statement' to include an else clause

Tags: python, list

How would I extent the following if statement so that the logic included an else clause. The pseudocode would function as follows.

- Ideal_Singers = each name that contains '(Beatle)' and either ('Paul', 'Yoko' or 'Ringo')
- if none of the names in the list meet these conditions, then Ideal_Singers = each name that contains 'Mick'

So far, I have this code:

```
Names = ["John Lennon (Beatle)",  "Paul McCartney (Beatle)", "Ringo Starr (Beatle)", "Yoko Ono (Beatle)", "Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)", "Brian Jones (Rolling Stone)", "Alex Jones (na)", "Adam Smith (na)"]
Ideal_Singers = [n for n in Names if "Beatle" in n and ("Paul" in n or "Ringo" in n or "Yoko" in n)]
print Ideal_Singers
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `any`:

```
names = ["John Lennon (Beatle)",  "Paul McCartney (Beatle)", "Ringo Starr (Beatle)", "Yoko Ono (Beatle)", "Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)", "Brian Jones (Rolling Stone)", "Alex Jones (na)", "Adam Smith (na)"]
names1 = [i for i in names if any(b in i for b in ['(Beatle)', 'Paul', 'Yoko','Ringo'])]
ideal_names = names1 or [i for i in names if 'Mick' in i]
```

Output:

```
['John Lennon (Beatle)', 'Paul McCartney (Beatle)', 'Ringo Starr (Beatle)', 'Yoko Ono (Beatle)']
```

Comment: Shouldn't the list NOT contain Mick Jagger since there are names in the list that meet the other conditions?

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Chris is right. The list should either contain:
["Paul McCartney (Beatle)", "Ringo Starr (Beatle)", "Yoko Ono (Beatle)"]
OR
["Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)"]
...depending on whether the items meet the conditions.

Comment: @Dongs14173 Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @Ajax1234 ... thanks. This helps, but there are now two lists: names1 and ideal_names. Ideally, 'ideal_names' would contain: ["Paul McCartney (Beatle)", "Ringo Starr (Beatle)", "Yoko Ono (Beatle)"] OR ["Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)"] ...depending on whether the items meet the conditions. Ie. there would only be one list - 'ideal_names'

Comment: @Dongs14173 `ideal_names` meets exactly the criteria you have given. It is `names1` if `names1` is non-empty, else it is all Micks. You could just combine the two comprehensions by an `or` if you are bothered by the auxililary variable ;)

Comment: @Dongs14173 `name1` is used in this case to store all the results of the first condition (Ideal_Singers = each name that contains '(Beatle)' and either ('Paul', 'Yoko' or 'Ringo')) and then used as a truthy value. This means that if `name1` is empty, then `ideal_list` will be created by Python's interpretation of empty lists. While `ideal_names` could be condensed into one line, it would take a total of three list comprehensions that one line.

Comment: @Ajax1234 ideal_names yields ''John Lennon (Beatle)''. The condition was that the name must contain: '(Beatle)' and either ('Paul', 'Yoko' or 'Ringo'), otherwise the name must contain 'Mick'. Sorry if I didn't explain. 

The pseudocode would function as follows.

List = each item that contains 'X' and either ('1', '2' or '3')
if none of the items in the list meet these conditions, then List = each item that contains 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that meets your criteria:

```
Names = [
    "John Lennon (Beatle)", 
    "Paul McCartney (Beatle)",
    "Ringo Starr (Beatle)",
    "Yoko Ono (Beatle)",
    "Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)",
    "Brian Jones (Rolling Stone)",
    "Alex Jones (na)",
    "Adam Smith (na)"
]
allowed_beatles = ["Paul", "Ringo", "Yoko"]
Ideal_Singers = [
    x for x in [
        [n for n in Names if "Beatle" in n and any(b in n for b in allowed_beatles)],
        [n for n in Names if 'Mick' in n]
    ]
    if x
]

Ideal_Singers = Ideal_Singers[0] if Ideal_Singers else []
print Ideal_Singers
```

Basically I make two lists, one for the Beatles condition and one for the Mick condition. Then I take the first of these lists that is not empty.

Output:

```
['Paul McCartney (Beatle)', 'Ringo Starr (Beatle)', 'Yoko Ono (Beatle)']
```